# Custom field calculation in wordpress using Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, countdown, custom-fields, calculation

I have implemented the code below in my site, to display a running timer. The site is running on Wordpress. At the moment the date is input in the code (so it applied site wide). I am looking to have a running timer on each post.

I need to change the code below so that I can use a **custom field** on each post called "expiry" as the date, instead of the hardwired date below *(newDate("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25).getTime()*

```
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

The above code is sourced from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp)

My site is [here](https://deepdarkwoods.com.au)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

below steps is your requirements:

1) in custom field expiry set return format as custom "F j, Y g:i:s"

example link (https://prnt.sc/pqg79l)

2)  add this function in functions.php

```
function functionname() {

    global $post;

    $field= get_field('expiry_date', $post->ID);
        echo '<input type="hidden" id="date" value="'.$field.'">';  
     }
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'functionname' );
```

3) in your js file add below script

```
 var $= jQuery;

    var d = $("#date").val();
    console.log(d);
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date(d).getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

      // Get today's date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
      + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      // If the count down is finished, write some text
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
```

make sure you have to add `<p id="demo"></p>` where you want to show in post

I have tried this code..It's totally working fine..I hope i have helped you by this

Comment: Hi Krishna,

Thank you for your response. I have been overseas and not had a chance to look at this, so appreciate your patience. I have updated all the code and although it doesn't return any errors, it does not print the date on the post page. Can you please take a look and see what I may have done incorrectly? 

Please note that I have changed all instances of the Id (Demo) to (date_exp). It is still not working. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Do I need to add an id wrapper to the custom field of "date_exp"?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @JasonStancombe Sorry for late reply, I have Edit my code and yes you need to add future date in post custom field see ss(https://prnt.sc/pqgal1) and I just Simple use my above code and its working just simply follows my steps.I have attached Image of admin so this is all here what i have done for this..